# applet communication using post method

Tags: java, servlets, post, applet, methods

I have an applet that is communicating with a servlet. I am communicating with the servlet using POST method. My problem is how do I send parameters to the servlet. Using GET method, this is fairly simple ( I just append the parameters to the URL after a ?). But using POST method how do I send the parameters, so that in the servlet side, I can use the statement :

```
message = req.getParameter("msg");
```

In the applet side, I establish POST method connection as follows :

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "servlet");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();

con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: The content type should by the way be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or just left away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to call (as you did):

```
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Then obtain the `OutputStream`:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
```

and write to it:

```
out.write("paramName=" + paramValue);
```

In the servlet, you can call `request.getParameter("paramName")`

[More details and instructions can be found here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Comment: And don't forget to `URLEncode` the parameter values (and names as well if they aren't fully ASCII). You can by the way concatenate multiple parameters by `&` like as in GET.

Comment: should I use (after the above statements),

out.flush();
out.close()

??

Comment: @mithun1538 on SO you are supposed to mark an answer as accepted, if it has worked for you.