# Jsp and applet communication

Tags: jsp, applet

I want to access the outputstream of the Applet from a JSP page where the applet is embedded. But it is giving `NullPointerException`. I have given the code below.

```
public class CheckJavaVersion extends Applet 
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private static Label versionCheck;
    public static String javaVersion;
    public static URLConnection connection;

    public void init() 
    {
        try
        {
            Color colFrameBackground = new Color(198, 0, 0);
            this.setBackground(colFrameBackground);
            versionCheck = new Label("Java Version:"+System.getProperty("java.version"));
            this.add(versionCheck);
            javaVersion = versionCheck.getText();
            javaVersion="testversion";

            String javaVersion1= URLEncoder.encode(javaVersion);
            URL currentPage=getDocumentBase();
            String protocol=currentPage.getProtocol();
            String host=currentPage.getHost();
            int port=currentPage.getPort();
            String urlSuffix=currentPage.toString();
            URL dataurl=new URL(protocol,host,port,urlSuffix);
            connection=dataurl.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
            PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(byteStream,true);
            out.print(javaVersion1);
            out.flush();
            System.out.println(byteStream.toString());
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",String.valueOf(byteStream.size()));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            byteStream.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
 }
```

JSP Page

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Communication</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:plugin code="com.applets.CheckJavaVersion" codebase="/AppletURLComm" type="applet">
</jsp:plugin>

<%
try
{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(CheckJavaVersion.connection.getInputStream()));
    String data;
    while((data=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
    {
        out.print(data);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The stacktrace is always a valuable piece of information. And anyway... what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850351/applet-and-jsp-communication

Comment: What is the point of telling the end-user the Java version on their own PC?  If this is for purposes of deploying other applets, use deployJava.js.  If it is strictly for informing the user, just display the information in the applet.  And while I'm here, that jsp:plugin element seems to be missing a width/height for the applet.  I do not know what it would do if they were missing, but note that if it defaults to width/height=0 that will cause all sorts of problems as anti-ad/malware plugins deem it a suspicious element and remove it entirely.

Comment: You can refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850351/applet-and-jsp-communication/27358112#27358112 Good Luck..........

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a variable from the applet in a JSP page scriptlet. The Applet is a Java app that will run in the client browser after the HTML is sent to the client, so this will never work.

Searching a bit here on SO you would find this: [applet communication using post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484119/applet-communication-using-post-method)